# Powerpoint-presentation-like python program

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a small project in which I must create a program using Python. The program must be something like a PowerPoint presentation, where you have a main slide with 8 links to 8 different slides. Each of these 8 secondary slides should show some images and text with and a click anywhere link to return to the main slide. The program must also work in full screen.

I have worked with Python before but not for developing GUIs. Can anyone recommend any libraries to use?

Comment: Have you tried wx: http://www.wxwidgets.org/? Other choices: http://docs.python.org/faq/gui.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I am completely new to GUIs with Python. Do you know if with wxwidgets could I set it my program to always work on fullscreen? and to add listeners (by example: wait for a click and do something depending on some timers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) or you can also use [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)

> PyGTK lets you to easily create programs with a graphical user interface using the Python programming language. The underlying GTK+ library provides all kind of visual elements and utilities for it.

But for small scale projects, I think `PyGTK`  will be more suitable.

Here is a list of all available options [GUI Python](http://docs.python.org/faq/gui.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have read about PyGTK, looks like a good choice. Have you worked with wxwidgets? @bpgergo also suggested that

Comment: No, i have not worked with wxwidgets.Most of my gui related programming is in `java swing` and on basis of that knowledge i tried learning `pygtk`.